# WPF DataTrigger only working 1 time

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I'm trying out WPF and I have an application with an `ObservableCollection` hooked up to a `ListView`. It adds the items perfectly and everything is falling together. It is taking in data from a live source and so item values are getting updated and rows are getting added. But now I want the most recent rows to be highlighted, text changed, something to show that this certain row is being changed. So I set up a data trigger and added a value to the `DataType` in the `ObservableCollection` called `RecentlyChanged`.  If its true, then set the text to red, otherwise text is black.

When I run this code the list items change to red and then never change back and I have tried everything and it is ticking me off. I've checked the debugger to and even when the value is `no` (I'm using strings `yes` and `no` because i wanted to try all sorts of data types) it stays red. Code for the data trigger is below:

--Edit: Added in the second datatrigger that i tried using before to no avail.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=RecentlyChanged}" Value="yes">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=RecentlyChanged}" Value="no">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
```

Comment: Does the underlying data type implement INotifyPropertyChanged? If so, make sure your control is set up to handle PropertyChanged events from each item.

Comment: It does not have an INotifyPropertyChanged. I figured if i just set the values myself it should handle this fine.

Comment: The thing is the ObservableCollection is only checking to see when the collection itself changes, i.e. When items are added or removed. The items themselves need to fire an event in order to trigger UI updates.

Comment: So if I implemented an INotifyPropertyChanged, then once one of them is changed and it is triggered how would i then change the font from the code since the listview was setup in the XML?

Comment: Thinking about it again, I realize your data trigger in the xaml should take care of the binding. The key is to fire the event.

Comment: Thanks Austin, i hooked it up with the INotifyPropertyChanged and that made it work, no other changed needed. Really appreciate it. (Would up vote but this is my first post so i do not believe i can do that yet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the `ObservableCollection` only reports changes to the collection itself, in other words, it fires a `CollectionChanged` event whenever items are added or removed, but not when properties of those items change. In order to achieve the desired result - updating a data trigger when an item's property changes - the item itself must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and fire the `PropertyChanged` event when the desired property is set.

In this case, you can use the following:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public class ListViewItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var propChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if(propChanged != null)
        {
            propChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private string recentlyChanged = "yes"; // Recently changed on creation
    public string RecentlyChanged
    {
        get { return recentlyChanged; }
        set {
            recentlyChanged = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RecentlyChanged");
        }
    }

    // ... define the rest of the class as usual

}
```

WPF magic should take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks Austin, glad you put that here so I could put that it is the accepted answer. Really appreciate your help!